# JQuery show images with id based on click (take 2)

Tags: jquery

A couple of months ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509625/jquery-show-images-with-id-based-on-click). I want to add an identical div with a different background. I'm wondering why the jQuery doesn't function in the second div? I'm seeing that the images show and hide in the first div only even when I click the little images in the second div.

```js
    $('#seatColors img, #frameColors img').click(function(e) {
      let target = e.target.id.includes('seat') ? 'seat' : 'frame'
      $('.' + target).hide();
      $('#' + e.target.id.replace(target, '').toLowerCase() + (target === 'seat' ? 'Back' : 'Frame')).show().addClass('color-overlay');

      console.log(target, '#' + e.target.id.replace(target, '').toLowerCase() + (target === 'seat' ? 'Back' : 'Frame'))
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="visualizer">
      <div id="chairContainer">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/background.jpg" class="background">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-red.png" id="redBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-black.png" id="blackBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-blue.png" id="blueBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-teal.png" id="tealBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-white.png" id="whiteBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-ww.png" id="wwBack" class="seat">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-red.png" id="redFrame" class="frame">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-black.png" id="blackFrame" class="frame">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-blue.png" id="blueFrame" class="frame">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-teal.png" id="tealFrame" class="frame">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-white.png" id="whiteFrame" class="frame">
        <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-ww.png" id="wwFrame" class="frame">
      </div>
      <div class="intro">
        <p>Select a seat and back color</p>
        <div id="seatColors">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="seatColor" id="seatRed">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="seatColor" id="seatBlack">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="seatColor" id="seatBlue">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="seatColor" id="seatTeal">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="seatColor" id="seatWhite">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="seatColor" id="seatWw">
        </div>

        <p>Select a frame color</p>
        <div id="frameColors">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="frameColor" id="frameRed">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="frameColor" id="frameBlack">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="frameColor" id="frameBlue">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="frameColor" id="frameTeal">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="frameColor" id="frameWhite">
          <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="frameColor" id="frameWw">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="visualizer">
       <div id="chairContainer">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/background.jpg" class="background">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/red-seats.png"  id="redBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/black-seats.png"  id="blackBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/blue-seats.png"  id="blueBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/teal-seats.png"  id="tealBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/white-seats.png"  id="whiteBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/ww-seats.png"  id="wwBack" class="seat">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/red-frame.png"  id="redFrame" class="frame">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/black-frame.png"  id="blackFrame" class="frame">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/blue-frame.png"  id="blueFrame" class="frame">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/teal-frame.png"  id="tealFrame" class="frame">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/white-frame.png"  id="whiteFrame" class="frame">
         <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/ww-frame.png"  id="wwFrame" class="frame">
 
     </div>
     <div class="intro">
       <p>Select a seat and back color *</p>
      <div id="seatColors">
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatRed"><br>Red</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatBlack"><br>Black</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatBlue"><br>Blue</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatTeal"><br>Teal</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatWhite"><br>White</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="seatColor" id ="seatWw"><br>Weatherwood</p>
    </div>

   <p>Select a frame color *</p>
       <div id="frameColors">
          <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameRed"><br>Red</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameBlack"><br>Black</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameBlue"><br>Blue</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameTeal"><br>Teal</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameWhite"><br>White</p>
        <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="frameColor" id ="frameWw"><br>Weatherwood</p>
      </div>
      <p>*The color shown on page load is a placeholder gray. It is not one of the colors available for purchase. This is for visualization purposes only. The actual colors may not appear exactly the same. <a href =/dealer-locater">Find and visit a dealer to see the products.</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[This is the site where I'm trying this.](http://seabreeze.otsandbox.com/color-visualizer)

Comment: Please edit you question and create a [mcve] using the snippet editor

Comment: I have copied the snippet to your question. Please  modify the HTML to what you mean

Comment: Thanks for the edit. In your edit of my post, I want to add another div like the html, but with different images just below the one posted. But the jQuery doesn't do anything in the second div, using the same setup. I'll grab the code.

Comment: You're setting the `target` variable to `"seat"` or `"frame"` and then hiding elements with that class. But there are no elements with the class "seat" or "frame" to hide.

Comment: Don’t tell me, show me. Add html and you can get images from placeholder.com

Comment: Can I give you a link to the site?

Comment: Just add the extra div in a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code works, I suggest you do not have two sets. If you insist the changes are quite intrusive

Here is what I did so far. 
Notice I work with class and closest so I changed all DIV IDs to class and all IDs on the images to data-id. I have extracted some changes to the CSS, it is cascading in a complex way.

```js
$('.seatColors img, .frameColors img').click(function(e) {
  let id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
  let target = id.includes('seat') ? 'seat' : 'frame'
  const $container= $(this).closest(".visualizer");
  $container.find('.' + target).hide(); // hide all of type
  
  // construct [data-id=whiteSeat] when seatWhite is clicked

  const showSelector = '[data-id=' + 
     id.replace(target, '').toLowerCase() + 
     (target === 'seat' ? 'Back' : 'Frame')+']'; // ternary if target is seat, use Back else use Frame

  console.log(id,target,showSelector);

  $(showSelector,$container).show().addClass('color-overlay');
});
```

```css
.visualizer {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around
}

.chairContainer {
  position: relative
}

.chairContainer img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px
}

.frame,
.seat {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none
}

.intro .frameColors,
.intro .seatColors {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 33px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
  text-align: center
}

.intro .frameColors p,
.intro .seatColors p {
  font-size: 7px
}

.intro .frameColors img,
.intro .seatColors img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50px
}
```

```html
<base href="http://seabreeze.otsandbox.com/" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qje3jyr.css"/>

<div class="visualizer">
  <div class="chairContainer">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/background.jpg" class="background">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-red.png" data-id="redBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-black.png" data-id="blackBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-blue.png" data-id="blueBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-teal.png" data-id="tealBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-white.png" data-id="whiteBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/seatback-ww.png" data-id="wwBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-red.png" data-id="redFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-black.png" data-id="blackFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-blue.png" data-id="blueFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-teal.png" data-id="tealFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-white.png" data-id="whiteFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/frame-ww.png" data-id="wwFrame" class="frame">
  </div>
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Select a seat and back color</p>
    <div class="seatColors">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatRed">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatBlack">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatBlue">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatTeal">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatWhite">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatWw">
    </div>

    <p>Select a frame color</p>
    <div class="frameColors">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameRed">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameBlack">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameBlue">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameTeal">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameWhite">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameWw">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="visualizer">
  <div class="chairContainer">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/background.jpg" class="background">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/red-seats.png" data-id="redBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/black-seats.png" data-id="blackBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/blue-seats.png" data-id="blueBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/teal-seats.png" data-id="tealBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/white-seats.png" data-id="whiteBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/ww-seats.png" data-id="wwBack" class="seat">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/red-frame.png" data-id="redFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/black-frame.png" data-id="blackFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/blue-frame.png" data-id="blueFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/teal-frame.png" data-id="tealFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/white-frame.png" data-id="whiteFrame" class="frame">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/scene21/ww-frame.png" data-id="wwFrame" class="frame">

  </div>
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Select a seat and back color *</p>
    <div class="seatColors">
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatRed"><br>Red</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatBlack"><br>Black</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatBlue"><br>Blue</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatTeal"><br>Teal</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatWhite"><br>White</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="seatColor" data-id="seatWw"><br>Weatherwood</p>
    </div>

    <p>Select a frame color *</p>
    <div class="frameColors">
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/red.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameRed"><br>Red</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/black.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameBlack"><br>Black</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/blue.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameBlue"><br>Blue</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/teal.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameTeal"><br>Teal</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/white.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameWhite"><br>White</p>
      <p><img src="/sites/default/files/color-visualizer/weatherwood.png" class="frameColor" data-id="frameWw"><br>Weatherwood</p>
    </div>
    <p>*The color shown on page load is a placeholder gray. It is not one of the colors available for purchase. This is for visualization purposes only. The actual colors may not appear exactly the same. <a href="/dealer-locater">Find and visit a dealer to see the products.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for what you've done. The data-id and classes seem to do what's expected. Everything works when I remove the .closest selector. But of course, it shows and hides the selected colors in both divs. If you have time and feel like it, could you help me understand what this line is doing? "[data-id=' + 
     id.replace(target, '').toLowerCase() + 
     (target === 'seat' ? 'Back' : 'Frame')+']';"

Comment: You're the best. The .visualizer class does indeed solve all the problems!

Comment: I updated with a comment on the selector constructor